# Python Docx - How to read the section (list of paragraphs, images, tables) that are linked to a word in another section using hyperlink

Tags: extract, docx, document, python-docx, text-extraction

Docx file has a paragraph where a work has hyperlink to internal (in same docx file) section.

I am trying to use python-docx library but stuck at finding the section using hyperlink found with a word.

I have tried python-docx library but could not get the the section using this.